# Reference of Sobolev space

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

currently I'm using [Krylov's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821846841), while consulting [Evans](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821807722) (too many details are left out, for my level).

Also, [Adams](http://books.google.nl/books?hl=zh-CN&lr=&id=R5A65Koh-EoC&oi=fnd&pg=PP2&dq=sobolev+spaces+adams&ots=guH7vnsa2E&sig=SRicepEuR5w0ml7kvSOY9Uy-eLU&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=sobolev%20spaces%20adams&f=false) 1975 version has been widely cited.

So besides these ones, which book in your mind would be best for using as a reference that provides complete treatment on Sobolev topics?

Cheers.

P.S: please feel free to move this topic to wiki cite, if necessary.

Comment: I like *A First Course on Sobolev Spaces* by Giovanni Leoni.

Comment: @LeonidKovalev The approach is quite different from the rest. As mentioned in the book, it requires less knowledge of functional analysis.

Comment: Different from Krylov's and Evans' for sure, since these two are PDE books, not Sobolev spaces books. If you like the functional analysis emphasis (interpolation etc), then Adams is the way to go. I prefer calculus to functional analysis, so for me Leoni works better. I also benefited from *Measure Theory...* by Evans and Gariepy, and, to a lesser degree, from *Weakly differentiable functions* by Ziemer. Ultimately, it depends on what you want to learn about Sobolev spaces

Answer (score 7):

Compiling the suggestions:

- *A First Course on Sobolev Spaces* by Giovanni Leoni (user-friendly exposition rooted in calculus)
- *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions* by Evans and Gariepy (not exclusively about Sobolev spaces, but covers the most essential results)
- *Weakly differentiable functions* by Ziemer (emphasis on BV)

And adding one more:

- *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations* by Haim Brezis: a widely used book oriented at functional analysis methods in PDE. Lots of exercises.